# Hide unused network interfaces in Zabbix

Tags: snmp, zabbix

I am interested in filtering out network interfaces that aren't connected to make things a bit simpler. I tried the filter

```
{#SNMPVALUE} : ^u|^1
```

on this page:https://www.zabbix.com/forum/showthread.php?t=37656

I added it to the filter on "Template OS Linux: Network interface discovery" but that just hides all network interfaces. I am not sure if there have been some updates in how I should filter that out in the newer versions of Zabbix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The forum thread you found talks about discovering SNMP interfaces, while the template you mentioned is for Linux.

For the agent interface discovery, {#SNMPVALUE} is not populated at all, thus your filter never matches.

To filter out interfaces, you would have to figure out the criteria. The [built-in interface discovery](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/discovery/low_level_discovery#discovery_of_network_interfaces) only returns the interface name, thus there is no way to filter interfaces by another criteria - unless you implement a [custom LLD](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/discovery/low_level_discovery#creating_custom_lld_rules).

Built-in support for filtering agent interfaces by state is requested in the comments of [ZBXNEXT-2286](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-2286).